# Disable keyboard backlight and Bluetooth at startup in Ubuntu mate 15.10

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, startup, backlight

I searched a lot for an answer for this question. Most of the answers that I find is to include the commands to disable the respective devices using the `rc.local` file. I tried this method but unfortunately it is not working. I still have the bluetooth and backlight 'on' at every startup.

This is the current state of my `/etc/rc.local` file:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
sh '/home/<myusername>/Documents/boff.sh'
sh '/home/<myusername>/Documents/dbl.sh'
exit 0
```

The file permissions are:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 378 Mar  6 17:21 /etc/rc.local
```

The `boff.sh` has the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo '0' > /sys/devices/platform/dell-laptop/leds/dell\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness
```

The `dbl.sh` has the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
rfkill block bluetooth
```

The permissions of these files are:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 <my username> <my username> 93 Mar  6 17:21 Documents/boff.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 <my username> <my username> 33 Mar  6 17:18 Documents/dbl.sh
```

This is the `lsusb` result

```
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 0bda:5754 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 04f3:2012 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c535 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0781:5567 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Blade
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please edit to include results for `lsusb` thanks

Comment: show `ls /sys/devices/platform/dell-laptop/leds/dell::kbd_backlight/`

Comment: edit question to add `cat /sys/devices/platform/dell-laptop/leds/dell::kbd_backlight/start_triggers`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the two lines you added to `/etc/rc.local` and just add

```
sleep 20
echo '0' > /sys/devices/platform/dell-laptop/leds/dell::kbd_backlight/brightness
```

Save, exit text editor and reboot

For the bluetooth we can use a udev rule to block bluetooth at start up

```
gksudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/81-bluetooth.rules
```

And copy the following

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="8087", ATTRS{idProduct}=="07dc", RUN+="/usr/sbin/rfkill block bluetooth"
```

Save and exit

Comment: I have tried it already but unfortunately that is not working !.

Comment: But the same command works in terminal with sudo?

Comment: Yes these commands work perfectly fine in terminal but is not getting executed during startup.

Comment: Did you do `sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local`

Comment: yes i did that too

Comment: Adding `sleep 20` to /etc/rc.local above the command might help if rc.local is executing before dell-laptop module is loaded

Comment: That too did'nt Work !

Comment: Please edit question to add `ls -l  /sys/devices/platform/dell-laptop/leds/dell::kbd_backlight/; lsmod | grep dell`  Can the Dell BIOS disable the keyboard backlight like my toshiba can?